# How can I prevent selection of text in div block which is blurred?

Tags: html, blur

I have a div block which is blurred. The div block has some text. Its looks blurred. But I can able to select the text and copy.
I would like to prevent this selection. What should I do?

Thank You.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: CSS: `user-select: none`

Comment: Is there anyway to stop showing this blurred block in the inspect element?

Comment: No, you can't stop it appearing in the Inspector, any more than you can stop it appearing when someone chooses to "View source". If the text is in your HTML then it's in your HTML. If you need to totally obscure it, you could try using an input field with type 'password' but, even then, it's going to be in the source somewhere. Otherwise, you're going to have to obscure it server-side as an image or similar. (Or just not including it in your HTML at all!)